# Expand dataframe with sequential dates based on a column of dates in R

Tags: r, date, na, expand

I'd like to expand my data frame based on my Date column so that there are new rows of Dates, in chronological order, between my current dates.  My Date column is chronological, runs across 5 years, and contains duplicate dates that I'd like to ignore.  I'd like the corresponding Group and Draw rows of the new rows to be "NA".

```
zz <- "Date Group Draw
1  2006-05-11    bb     T
2  2006-05-11    bb     F
3  2006-05-14    aa     T
4  2006-05-16    aa     T
5  2006-05-20    cc     F
6  2006-05-20    bb     F
7  2006-05-21    aa     T"

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

So I would want my new data frame to look like this:

```
xx <- "Date Group Draw
1  2006-05-11    bb     T
2  2006-05-11    bb     F
3  2006-05-12    NA     NA
4  2006-05-13    NA     NA
5  2006-05-14    aa     T
6  2006-05-15    NA     NA
7  2006-05-16    aa     T
8  2006-05-17    NA     NA
9  2006-05-18    NA     NA
10 2006-05-19    NA     NA
11 2006-05-20    cc     F
12 2006-05-20    bb     F
13 2006-05-21    aa     T"

Output <- read.table(text=xx, header = TRUE)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.  I am new to R, and have been trying to do this manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should work fine:

```
merge(
    x = data.frame(
        Date = seq.Date(min(df$Date), max(df$Date), by = "day")
    ),
    y = df,
    all.x = TRUE
)
#          Date Group  Draw
# 1  2006-05-11    bb  TRUE
# 2  2006-05-11    bb FALSE
# 3  2006-05-12  <NA>    NA
# 4  2006-05-13  <NA>    NA
# 5  2006-05-14    aa  TRUE
# 6  2006-05-15  <NA>    NA
# 7  2006-05-16    aa  TRUE
# 8  2006-05-17  <NA>    NA
# 9  2006-05-18  <NA>    NA
# 10 2006-05-19  <NA>    NA
# 11 2006-05-20    cc FALSE
# 12 2006-05-20    bb FALSE
# 13 2006-05-21    aa  TRUE
```

---

All this is doing is creating a date sequence spanning the range of your actual data, and then performing a left join.

---

And the same idea, using `data.table`:

```
dt[dt[,.(Date = seq.Date(min(Date), max(Date), by = "day"))], on = .(Date)]
#           Date Group  Draw
#  1: 2006-05-11    bb  TRUE
#  2: 2006-05-11    bb FALSE
#  3: 2006-05-12    NA    NA
#  4: 2006-05-13    NA    NA
#  5: 2006-05-14    aa  TRUE
#  6: 2006-05-15    NA    NA
#  7: 2006-05-16    aa  TRUE
#  8: 2006-05-17    NA    NA
#  9: 2006-05-18    NA    NA
# 10: 2006-05-19    NA    NA
# 11: 2006-05-20    cc FALSE
# 12: 2006-05-20    bb FALSE
# 13: 2006-05-21    aa  TRUE
```

---

```
zz <- "Date Group Draw
1  2006-05-11    bb     T
2  2006-05-11    bb     F
3  2006-05-14    aa     T
4  2006-05-16    aa     T
5  2006-05-20    cc     F
6  2006-05-20    bb     F
7  2006-05-21    aa     T"

df <- read.table(
    text = zz, 
    header = TRUE
)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date) 

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(read.table(text = zz, header = TRUE))[,Date := as.Date(Date)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked really well.  I would update your answer to add library(data.table), since it didn't work for me until I found this package.  Thanks again @nrussell

Answer (score 3):

Using data from @nrussell's post, another option is `complete` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
complete(df, Date = full_seq(Date, 1))
## A tibble: 13 × 3
#         Date  Group  Draw
#       <date> <fctr> <lgl>
#1  2006-05-11     bb  TRUE
#2  2006-05-11     bb FALSE
#3  2006-05-12     NA    NA
#4  2006-05-13     NA    NA
#5  2006-05-14     aa  TRUE
#6  2006-05-15     NA    NA
#7  2006-05-16     aa  TRUE
#8  2006-05-17     NA    NA
#9  2006-05-18     NA    NA
#10 2006-05-19     NA    NA
#11 2006-05-20     cc FALSE
#12 2006-05-20     bb FALSE
#13 2006-05-21     aa  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, here is my crude take:

```
date  <- format(seq.Date(from=as.Date(paste(2006, '05', '11', sep='-'), 
                                   '%Y-%m-%d'), 
                      to  =as.Date(paste(2006, 05, '21', sep='-'), 
                                   '%Y-%m-%d'), 
                      by  = "day"), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

The above generates the list of dates. You can then use a left join of the `date` above to your data.table.

Comment: For this, I wouldn't be able to put my entire date range in, because there are some dates that are duplicates, per my example. @kquach